# jQuery selector to select 2 and 3rd columns of a table

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to select only 2 and 3 columns of my "services" table.

For example,

```
$('table[class="services"] tr td:nth-child(3)')
```

selects the 3rd column, is there a way to select both 2nd *and* third columns with a single selector?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$('table[class="services"] tr td:nth-child(3), table[class="services"] tr td:nth-child(2)')
```

Comment: I guess its selecting second & third columns from all the rows, if I want to select only second column of the first row, how can I do that? I have tried something like this: $("#ChallanGrid tr:eq(1) td:(3)"), but its not working.

Answer (score 3):

You could split it to avoid repetition of the first part of the selector:

```
$('table.services tr td').filter(':nth-child(2), :nth-child(3)')
```

Also note that `table.services` is the "correct" way to select by class in CSS!

Answer (score 1):

you can do:

```
$('table.services tr td:nth-child(2), table.services tr td:nth-child(3)')
```

Answer (score 0):

OR... you can do it like this:

```
$('table.services tr td:nth-child(n+2):nth-child(-n+3)')
```

Also useful for a range of columns such as columns 4 to 7 (if needed):

```
$('table.services tr td:nth-child(n+4):nth-child(-n+7)')
```